# Linux/Apache: Give FTP User ability to write to folders

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ftp, ubuntu-10.04

I am pretty sure this there is an easy solution to this problem but I just can't seem to find the answer.

Here is my issue. I have installed vsftpd on my ubuntu 10.04. I created a group and a user for this and set up the password. I can now ftp to my server and read all the files I want; however, I cannot write/edit/delete any folders. I have made sure I have changed the group/user of /var/www to the newly created group and given 777 permissions recursively. I still can't edit/upload/delete anything at all.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: look at your vsftpd.conf - out of the box all write commands are disabled

Answer (score 1):

check that `write_enable` is erm enabled
    write_enable=YES

The default is NO and it affects the following commands `STOR`, `DELE`, `RNFR`, `RNTO`, `MKD`, `RMD`, `APPE` and `SITE` which can change the filesystem.